# How to store a boolean value after my app is killed

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
+ (void)setUISoundsEnabled:(BOOL)UISoundsEnabled
{
    __UISoundsEnabled = UISoundsEnabled;

}
```

The app has a preferences page that lets me toggle different alert sounds on and off. When I toggle the alert sound off, this UISoundsEnabled bool is set to: YES, and vice versa.

However when the app crashes, or I kill it (not just close it); I believe the bool is not being stored, because despite what the switch says (not to play sounds) it still plays sounds.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb here and say you might be biting off more than you can chew, especially if you're new to programming. You need to learn more basic concepts before you dive straight in to code like this.

Comment: Look into `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Or at the very least you need to be a lot better at using Google and the (relatively good) Apple documentation.

Comment: definitely agree! However I'm an intern and need to figure this out. All my time is devoted to studying documentation, or completing projects for my company. I had already acquainted myself with NSUserDefaults, but thanks for the advice, I'm definitely studying basics as often as I'm working on tasks like this

Answer (score 2):

Set a boolean in your `NSUserDefaults` instance:

```
+ (void)setUISoundsEnabled:(BOOL)UISoundsEnabled
{
    __UISoundsEnabled = UISoundsEnabled;
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setBool:UISoundsEnabled forKey:@"soundsEnabled"];
}
```

And then to check to see if the sounds are enabled when loading your application and configuring your preferences view and take action on it:

```
[[NSUserDeafults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"soundsEnabled"];
```

This way, your value persists through crashes and closures.

Comment: thank you for that! I've had nsuserdefaults set up several times but never got the value to persist after the app closed.The main problem I've been having is getting the app to retrieve the value. The code you provided at the end seems like it will do it, but I'm having trouble finding a place to insert it. I'm not working within a view controller but my first guess would have been to put it somewhere under viewdidload if it was

Answer (score 0):

This is what I figured out!

In the view controller I have a notification that listens for changes to UISoundsEnabled

```
- (void)preferencesDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
NSMutableArray *changedPreferences = note.object;
if ([changedPreferences containsObject:@"localPlayUISounds"]) {
[FHSSound setUISoundsEnabled:PREFS.localPlayUISounds];
}
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
```

[super viewDidLoad];

[self setSoundPreferences];
    }

and lastly setting the preferences at launch

```
#pragma mark (launch)
- (void)setSoundPreferences
 {
[FHSSound setUISoundsEnabled:PREFS.localPlayUISounds];
[FHSSound setAlertSoundsEnabled:PREFS.localPlayAlertSounds];
}
```